# Is canvas drawing slow?

Tags: android, performance, drawing

I have my custom view class which displays game map on the screen. I am drawing it with `onDraw()` overriding and using `Canvas` drawing methods inside.

Now I wan't to animate my map, for example with smooth scrolling.

Will `onDraw()` work fast enough on most devices? Or I should choose some other drawing methods? Which ones?

Comment: Try it and see what kind of performance you get. I think it highly depends on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I can't test on all devices. If I get good performance on my device it can be not true for others. Is there some performance rating of various methods or something?

Comment: With so many devices and so many draw methods there is no way to tell. A rough estimate I use is that if the number of pixels you draw is less than 1.5 times the number of pixels on screen, you should get with Canvas 50-60 fps. You should count also transparent pixels you draw.

Comment: I don't draw pixels, I draw lines, figures, text and bitmaps. Is this the same you were telling about?

Comment: everything is pixels eventually. Count just the bitmaps, it will give you a good rough estimate

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a gamethread that renders with 30 FPS all modern devices will handle it. 30 FPS also counts for the updating frequency, so increasing FPS makes moving faster as well. All android devices today will be able to handle 30 and 60 FPS. You do not have to worry at all about it. The canvas draws fast enough and animation works fine as well